# Extjs - Add item to store manually

Tags: javascript, extjs, store

I want to manually add items to a combo box.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.myStore', {    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'Ext.data.Field'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'myStore',
        fields: [
            {
                name: 'nameField'
            }
        ]
    }, cfg)]);
}
});
```

.

```
onfocus: function(component, e, eOpts){
    var comp = component.up('#viewContainer');
    var tgrid = comp.down('#netTable');
    console.log(component);
    var arr = tgrid.store.collect('dbColumn');
    //alert(arr);
}
```

I want to add arr, which an array of data , to the store. How do I go about it

I tried the following, but it didn't work

```
var store =  Ext.getStore('myStore');
var menuPoint = Ext.create('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', 
   {
        nameField: 'child'
    });
store.add(menuPoint);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561075/ext-4-1-1-add-new-record-to-store

Comment: thanks, settin to local fixes the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var store =  Ext.getStore('myStore');
var menuPoint = Ext.create('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', 
   {
        nameField: 'child'
    });
store.loadData(menuPoint,true);
```

The second parameter to `loadData()` is the key.  Setting it to true tells the store to append this record to the existing set of records already in there.